# Unable to copy the clipboard details on a remote machine while running tests from ALM

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-quality-center, alm, hp-uft

I'm using following script for Recovery scenario in UFT by calling the function `ErrorrecoveryHandler(object)`:

```
Function getClipBoardText(object)
    Dim objCB
    Set objCB = CreateObject("Mercury.Clipboard")
    Dim sClipText
    ' Assign clipboard contents to string variable sClipText.
    sClipText = objCB.GetText
    'getClipBoardText = sClipText
    Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "There was an exception during execution", sClipText
End Function

Function ErrorrecoveryHandler(object)
    JavaWindow("LightSpeedEVoMain").JavaDialog("Error").JavaButton("Copy to Clipboard").Click
    Dim objCB
    Set objCB = CreateObject("Mercury.Clipboard")
    errorDetails = objCB.GetText
    Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "There was an exception during execution", errorDetails
    JavaWindow("LightSpeedEVoMain").JavaDialog("Error").JavaButton("OK").Click
End Function
```

When I run my application on a VM through ALM and there is an error, the above function call is triggred, but I'm getting an error:

> Run Error:
> ActiveX component can't create object: 'Mercury.Clipboard'

Answer (score 0):

That ActiveX object should be registered as part of the base QTP/UFT install.  You may want to try re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in for example http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Number=203008, `Mercury.Clipboard` is **available only if you install QTPPlus**.

Without it, there is no ClipboardObject.dll, which is the DLL that implements `Mercury.Clipboard`.

Answer (score 0):

Strange but true: if you install UFT including the 'Flight' example project, you will also install the ActiveX component.
Then you will have no problem using the Mecury Clipboard.